# VS Studio Crashes hard with "encountered a user-defined breakpoint" error on any config file

Tags: visual-studio, configuration-files

I have a odd problem here I can't figure out.

[alt text http://billrob.com/images/studioerror.jpg](http://billrob.com/images/studioerror.jpg)

This happens each time I open the web.config file in my project.  Studio crashes immediately after clicking close.  Clicking debug just opens and empty Studio with the debugger attached to nothing.

I even resorted to open studio 2008 naked, without and project or solution, and then manually browsed to the web.config.  It still crashes.

Other info:

All *.config files with crash as soon as the file opens.
This occurs in both VS 2005 and 2008.
Any file named .config, whether a .cs file renamed, or an empty text file called bob.config.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where can I see the list of addins?  I've been trying to go through the menus looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at your packages installed for Visual Studio. They are registered in the registry under:

```
Visual Studio 2008
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0Exp\Packages 

Visual Studio 2005
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0Exp
```

If you have a lot, I say kill them all.  And then reinstall your specific addons (such as CodeSmith or VisualSVN).

For reference, this is my fresh new install of Visual Studio 2008 SP1 on Windows 7 RTM.  Only 1 plugin, and it's for SQL Server's SSIS:

[registery http://eduncan911.com/blog/thumbnail/billrob-stackoverflow.png](http://eduncan911.com/blog/thumbnail/billrob-stackoverflow.png)